# Importing external module

Tags: typescript

I would like to use toastr in a Typescript project.  I have enabled AMD.
I have added the d.ts file for it.

In app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="scripts/typings/toastr/toastr.d.ts" />
toastr.info("Test");
```

This compiles and runs, but fails of course because toastr.js is not loaded.

How to I require() toastr?

Have tried:

```
import toastr = require("toastr");
```

but it gives me a message saying toastr cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the definitions to allow you to use `import/require` : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/4499

Comment: Thank You @basarat, that resolves that error message.  However, requirejs now tries to download it from /toastr instead of from Scripts/toastr. How do I specify the correct path?

Comment: @GregGum: add a line to your require-config to specify the [`baseUrl`](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl) for loading all scripts.